# Can't get childNodes computedStyle

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can't get childNodes computedStyle, getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: 
>   Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not
>   of type 'Element'

```
let wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-attribute="wrapper"]');
  wrappers = Array.prototype.slice.call(wrappers);

  wrappers.forEach((el) => {
    let wrappersChildren = wrappers.slice.call(el.childNodes, 0);

    wrappersChildren.forEach((el) => {
      const childrenWidth = window.getComputedStyle(el).width;
      ...
```

Where i did mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Using `el.childNodes` is the mistake, as it returns text nodes too.
Use `el.children` instead

Here is the fixed code:

```
let wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-attribute="wrapper"]');
  wrappers = Array.prototype.slice.call(wrappers);

  wrappers.forEach((el) => {
    let wrappersChildren = wrappers.slice.call(el.children, 0);

    wrappersChildren.forEach((el) => {
      const childrenWidth = window.getComputedStyle(el).width;
      ...
```

Comment: but el.children return only immediate childrens, not all nested elements. Isn't it?

Comment: @VladimirHumeniuk, childNodes and children are both immediate children, they do not contain nested elements / text nodes

Comment: You can use document.querySelectorAll('css selector to elements');

Comment: @VladimirHumeniuk Change your selector to include * which selects all elements, ie `[data-attribute="wrapper"] *` which will select every element inside an element with data-attribute equaling wrapper.